# :last-child property not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div class="top-tab">
         <div class="top-tab-box"></div>
         <div class="top-tab-box"></div>
         <div class="top-tab-box"></div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<style>
.top-tab-box
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: #000;
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;

}
.top-tab div.top-tab-box:last-child{
   background: #e7e7e7;
}
</style>
```

I have this html code.if I removed

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

then last-child worked

but with this clear div last-child property not working

Answer (score 1):

When the clearing div is not present, the tab-box div is the last-child, but not otherwise. (At the moment, the clearing div is the last child, so your rule can't apply to the last tab-box.) Try giving your #wrapper `overflow: hidden;` instead of using the clearing div.

Comment: Or instead of floating, use `display:inline-block`.

Comment: if i remove clear div then bottom div overlap this div

Comment: That means there's something else a bit dodgy going on. You'd need to provide a link to the actual situation for a better answer, but a non-semantic clearing div is not the right solution.

Comment: an other option is to clear the floats with a pseudo element

Answer (score 1):

That's because `<div class="clear"></div>` is the actual :last-child

I suggest you to use ':last-of-type' instead of `:last-child` and don't use a `<div>` for the clearing.

Try this

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div class="top-tab">
         <div class="top-tab-box"></div>
         <div class="top-tab-box"></div>
         <div class="top-tab-box"></div>
         <!-- don't use a div for .clear-->
<span class="clear"></span>
    </div>
```

and css

```
.top-tab div:last-of-type{
   background: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Also remember to change the .clear selector in css to something like `.clear {clear:both;display:block;}` if you are going to use `'

**

### Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4psdN/

**

Comment: I just edited my post with additional information about using span as clearing element, and added a jsfiddle that should guide you.
Maybe you didn't see it yet :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use nth-last-child(2) to select the second-last element of the div:
http://jsfiddle.net/JX58w/

```
#wrapper div div:nth-last-child(2){
   background: red;
}
```